# Fancybox not showing uploaded pictures with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fancybox, carrierwave

I am trying to use fancybox to display images. When I use static images, as the existing in the assets folder, all works fine. However, when I try to use uploaded images which were saved using carrierwave, it always puts the next message: "The requested content cannot be loaded.".

The code that I am using to display the picture is the next:

**app/models/upload.rb**

```
class Upload
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  mount_uploader :file, UploadUploader

  # Fields
  field :file, type: String
  field :filename, type: String
  field :file64, type: String
  field :size_file, type: Integer
  field :file_extension, type: String

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :file

  # Hooks
  before_validation do
    if not self.file.url and self.filename and self.file64
      sio = CarrierwaveStringIO.new( Base64.decode64( self.file64 ) )
      sio.original_filename = self.filename
      self.file = sio
      self.filename = nil
      self.file64 = nil
    end
  end

  before_save do
    self.size_file = self.size
    self.file_extension = File.extname( self.file.to_s )[1..-1]
  end

  def base64
    MIME::Types.type_of( self.file.url ).first.content_type
  end

  def size
    self.file.size
  end
end
```

**app/views...**

```
...
= link_to upload_path( upload.id ), class: 'fancybox' do
  = image_tag upload_path( upload.id ), height: 174, width: 256
...
```

**app/assets/javascript...**

```
...
$( ".fancybox" ).fancybox()
...
```

I have tried lots of things to make the code works. For example, in the view, I change the "href" of the link_tag and the "src" of the image_tag, to the show path of the upload but it still does not work. Also, I tried to load the picture using AJAX and using the "content" property of fancybox but I obtained the same result. Finally, I created a show action for the upload controller in which I only display the picture and used the "content" and "type" properties of fancybox to use html, but I can not see the picture (no routes matches with the url of the picture, not the show action).

I have spent a lot of hours trying to make it works but I can not find anything. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**app/controllers/upload_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    if request.format.html?
      content_type = MIME::Types.type_for( @upload.file.url ).first.content_type
      send_file @upload.file.url, content_type: content_type, disposition: 'inline', :x_sendfile => true
    else
      respond_with @upload, api_template: :general
    end
  end

  ...
```

**app/uploaders/upload_...**

```
class UploadUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "#{ Rails.root.to_s }/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{ Rails.root.to_s }/tmp/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png bmp tif)
  end
end
```

**app/views/uploads/show.html.haml**

```
= image_tag @upload.file_url.to_s
```

Comment: is image getting loaded using uploaded url. if so, and if url is public, can you add your code in jsfiddle

Comment: I am not sure about if the image is getting loaded because when I see the url with firebug, it shows me a broken image in that url. How can I check if the picture is loaded?. Sorry but I can not add my code in jsfiddle for the moment.

Comment: copy that url and paste in new browser tab.. if you have hosted in amazon then it should show what is problem with accessing image url. There might be cases where the user is unauthorized to access image, due to configuration settings in server. And if you made images public in server then you should be able to see image for sure. (update question with your image url)

Comment: I am working in localhost, so the pictures are uploaded in my computer. I have tried what you said and the browser shows me it (which is the route of a file in my computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying type option, forces content type. it can be set to 'image', 'ajax', 'iframe', 'swf' or 'inline'

```
$( ".fancybox11" ).fancybox({
type: 'iframe', width: 380, height: 280
})
```

Refer this link [fancybox api options](http://fancybox.net/api).

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help. I have uploaded the topic with more code of the Upload resource.